# clicking to a specific slide on another page bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm trying to get this going on a bootstrap build, where on one page there are clickable states, however, these will go to a specific slide on another page.

I'm still having a tough time understanding this. My buddy, who's a Javascript developer wrote out some code, but I can't make sense of it.

```
<script>
function goToSlide(x) {
    console.log('going to slide '+x)
    $("#myCarousel").carousel(x);
 }
</script>
```

so from page 1, click, goes to specific slide on page 2

Comment: Have you perhaps tried using anchor tags? so then if you click that reference /page2.html#slide3

Answer (score 1):

If it's only one link going to another slide on the other page I would try something like this:

```
function goToSlide() {
   document.location.href = page2.html;
   var div = document.getElementById("slide2");
   div.className = "item active";

   var otherDiv = document.getElementById("slide1");
   otherDiv.className = "item";
}
```

Comment: it's actually going to be five clickable links that go to individual slides in page 2

Answer (score 0):

Take a peek at the carousel methods:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-usage

You would probably want to use `.carousel(number)`, in conjunction with URL parameters or hash tags as @Lukas mentioned above. Just watch for the hash/parameter in the URL, and have the carousel load with that slide active.